# What does it mean physically when a distribution is in exponential family

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I've been learning machine learning by Standford's online lecture for few days, in Lecture 4 the instructor introduced GLM(Generalized Linear Model) and exponential family.

x, y, p represents features, result to be predicted, distribution's parameter respectively.

He concluded that if we assume P(y|x;p) is in exponential family and if the problem is a binomial classification problem, that is, y∈{0,1}, then P(1|x;p) is logistic function.

I'm ok with the mathematical part, but I don't know what does it mean when we assume that P(y|x;p) is in exponential family, what's the condition in reality that this assumption is true?

I know about the Central Limit Theory, it states that a random variable that is 
the summation of other independent random variables, will approximate to Gaussian distribution, does it relate to my question?

Answer (score 0):

The exponential family of distributions include all probability distributions whose probability density (or probability mass) functions can be expressed according to f(x|T) = h(x)c(T)exp(sum(w_i(T)t_i(x))) for variable x, and parameter vector T, with each w_i just a function of the parameters and each t_i just a function of the data.  To us, the form itself probably doesn't itself matter.

The exponential family includes quite a few of the canonical probability distributions: the normal, exponential, gamma, chi-squared, beta, Dirichlet, Bernoulli, categorical, Poisson, Wishart, and Inverse Wishart.  So it's actually a form that is very adaptable to a wide range of data processes.

So why go to the trouble of including it as a model assumption?  It turns out that the exponential family has a whole bunch of nice mathematical properties that are no doubt employed by the model you're using.  So, in short, assuming the exponential family is more than likely just a mathematical assumption to make the math workable.  The good news is it's not a very restrictive assumption.